# Transaction in Lucene

Tags: transactions, lucene

I am aware that lucene supports transactional ACID properties.

As records are inserted each record is indexed in Lucene too.

If transactions are done to database, then to indexes are done. But when it gets failed, MYSQL provides with rollback and the other records are not inserted in that transaction.

When DB rollback even the indexes created at that time should also be rollback.

Has Lucene provides such functionality?
Is it possible to bind MYSQL transaction and Lucene indexing for the records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Has Lucene provides such functionality?

Lucene does provide rollback, see [`IndexWriter.rollback()`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html).

> Is it possible to bind MYSQL transaction and Lucene indexing for the
>   records?

Not out of the box, no. But there are [frameworks](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/search.html) which can do this for you.